# AVD launching error - android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch AVD but it doesn't response here what it gives me.
i re-installed it with no change although i have looked at some answers of related questions that suggest to kill adb.exe and i did too :(

```
C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Comment: how many avd emulators do you have..?

Comment: only one i created

Comment: can you check by reducing ram size(Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M)

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto he mentioned in the question that he tried kill adb. see the question before you comment

Comment: what about this line : adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server

Comment: @andrew what are the configuration you have given like ram and all.. And what is the system configuration?

Comment: i chose one of the devices already downloaded with android studio and my system is windows 7